# unsigned long to float?

Tags: objective-c

How does one convert an unsigned long number to a float in Objective-C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typecast it the same as in C.
Typecasting is explicitly converting one data type to another.

```
unsigned long myLong = 5;
float myFloat = (float)myLong;
```

(float)myFloat is the key.  The datatype (i.e. float, int) goes in the parentheses and directly after it comes the variable you're typecasting.

http://docs.hp.com/en/B3901-90007/ch05s05.html has further information.

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C is remarkably similar to C. In fact, it can be implemented as a layer on top of standard C with runtime support for the creation and destruction of objects.

What that generally means is that most things you can do in C, you can also do in Objective-C. Casting an unsigned long to a float is done (in both languages) as follows.

```
unsigned long ul = 7;
float f = (float)ul;
```